# Crystal Reports Error Boolean Required errorKind

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have been working on some Crystal Reports for one of our clinics but for some reason not I nor our other IT team members understand why this error is happening. So first here is the error specifically given:

> A boolean is required here. Details: errorKind Error in File
>   CPTCharges {FD775771-FD54-40B1-891A-87AFD9539789}.rpt: Error in
>   formula CPTCodes: 'if {CPTCodes.Day} = "0" Then ' A boolean is
>   required here. Details: errorKind

The report has a few formula fields. The one that it is specifically referring to is:

```
if {CPTCodes.Day} = "0" Then
    if {CPTCodes.D0} = "1" Then
        {CPTCodes.CPTID} 
    else ""
else if {CPTCodes.Day} = "3" Then
    if {CPTCodes.D3} = "1" Then
        {CPTCodes.CPTID} 
    else ""
else if {CPTCodes.Day} = "4" Then
    if {CPTCodes.D4} = "1" Then
        {CPTCodes.CPTID} 
    else ""
else if {CPTCodes.Day} = "5" Then
    if {CPTCodes.D5} = "1" Then
        {CPTCodes.CPTID} 
    else ""
else if {CPTCodes.Day} = "6" Then
    if {CPTCodes.D6} = "1" Then
        {CPTCodes.CPTID} 
    else ""
else if {CPTCodes.Day} = "FET" Then
    if {CPTCodes.FET} = "1" Then
        {CPTCodes.CPTID} 
    else "";
```

{CPTCodes.Day} returns either 0,3,4,5,6,FET. Each corresponding {CPTCodes.?} will either be a 1 or a 0. {CPTCodes.CPTID} is a code given from the database corresponding to a procedure that we are charging for.

All this information is being sent in correctly from the previous page. Originally I tried doing a simple switch, but since that wasnt working I tried nested if statements. That doesn't seem to be working. Things Ive tried that ive seen answers for online that hasn't worked:

- 1) Checked the return type of the dataset incase there was a
  discrepancy
- 2) Used both switch and regular nested if statements
- 3) Erased and rewritten formula
- 4) Try using true/false instead of "0","1",etc. (which wouldn't work for my needs anyway)
- 5) Made sure the formulas is under the "Formula Fields" folder in the
  formula editor

The only other thing that we found is that maybe our solution isnt compiling in the correct bit format (well not really a solution...its being run directly on server as opposed to as a solution that I can push updates from....not my choice!). So when I went to check the configuration, all I see is "anyCPU". I dont see an option for x86 or x64.

I am absolutely lost as to why these aren't working!! My last resort is to create a word doc using HTML which I really dont want to do. If I am missing any information that might help in figuring out whats up, please let me know. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!! Thank you!

**EDIT:**

New code, tried using this piece of code to see if anything would happen, or if I would get the same error. I got the same error. Below is the code:

```
if {CPTCodes.Day} = "0" AND {CPTCodes.D0} = "1" Then {CPTCodes.CPTID} Else ""
```

Also to just test the "boolean required here" BS, I put in this code snippet and get an error when saving that "a string is required here":

```
if {CPTCodes.Day} = true then "true" else "false";
```

Comment: Have you tried: if cStr({CPTCodes.Day}) = "0" AND cStr({CPTCodes.D0}) = "1" Then {CPTCodes.CPTID} Else "" ? I know you shouldn't have to, but it wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic format for an IF expression is ...

```
if expr_1 then (do_1;do_2) else (do_3;do_4)
```

for nested IFs use either ...

```
if expr_1 then (do_1;do_2) 
else if expr_2 then (do_3;do_4)
else (do_5;do_6}
```

or...

```
if expr_1 then 
     (do_1;
      do_2) 
else (do_3;
      if expr_2 then 
         (do_4;
          do_5)
      else
         (do_6;
          do_7)
     )
```

You could also try:

```
if {CPTCodes.Day} = "0" AND {CPTCodes.D0} = "1" Then
{CPTCodes.CPTID} 
else ""
```

As far as the boolean error goes, what is the datatype for {CPTCodes.Day}?

Comment: well thats the weird thing. {CPTCodes.Day} is a string datatype. So IDK what is going on with that. I dont get the error in the formula editor, just when I go to open the report. Ill report back on the code change.

Comment: Edited main post with the snippet I tried. Didn't work. Thank you for the correct use of nested if's though, much appreciated for later use!

Comment: I would try with just one "if" condition and see what happens Then start building up the statement.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yeah, I also added an "answer" to this as to what I had to do. I upped yours though because you got it right in one of your comments.

Comment: I see. Good job figuring it out!

Answer (score 2):

So I tried the if statements that you suggested and using cStr to see what I got. That worked...here is what I had to use:

```
if cStr({CPTCodes.Day}) = "D0" AND cStr({CPTCodes.D0}) = "True" Then cStr({CPTCodes.CPTID}) Else
if cStr({CPTCodes.Day}) = "D3" AND cStr({CPTCodes.D3}) = "True" Then cStr({CPTCodes.CPTID}) Else
if cStr({CPTCodes.Day}) = "D4" AND cStr({CPTCodes.D4}) = "True" Then cStr({CPTCodes.CPTID}) Else
if cStr({CPTCodes.Day}) = "D5" AND cStr({CPTCodes.D5}) = "True" Then cStr({CPTCodes.CPTID}) Else
if cStr({CPTCodes.Day}) = "D6" AND cStr({CPTCodes.D6}) = "True" Then cStr({CPTCodes.CPTID}) Else
if cStr({CPTCodes.Day}) = "FET" AND cStr({CPTCodes.FET}) = "True" Then cStr({CPTCodes.CPTID});
```

It was a weird workaround but still worked. Thanks!!